# Install new Shingles with Copper flashing

Tags: roof, copper, flashing, shingles

I had a roofing company install new roof with new shingles and copper flashing (pictures attached). Can the experts please provide suggestions if the copper flashing looks fine or does something needs to be changed/modified?
Thanks and Regards.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there step flashing under the roof part that is sloped? if not you are in for trouble. Other things don't look right either, but if there is flashing under the, what I hope is counter flashing then it may be good. The reason I say this is, the flashing on the horizontal is not turned onto the roof enough to do well. The flashing on the sloped part, the little part turned over the roof will do nothing, unless there is step flashing under it. I have no idea why they turned out what they did over the roof.

Comment: Yeah there is aluminum step flashing under the copper flashing. What i am not sure about is should the base of copper flashing go under the shingle or is this ok.

Comment: For a copper job it looks sub par:  Other than the step flashing is the flashing embedded in the mortar? It looks like it is on the right side of the photo but not on the left so it is totally useless where it is not embedded. The flashing should be in the grout between the bricks a minimum of 3/8” I know some contractors that insist on 1/2” minimum.

Comment: I hope the aluminum is isolated from the copper. They are incompatible metals and the copper will destroy what aluminum it touches

Comment: @Ed The copper flashing is between the bricks but they put a clear jelly/glue like substance all over between the copper and bricks. Also there are lot of scratches/marks on the copper. I was expecting a more shinny copper without scratches. I wonder if I have to ask them to remove the scratches.

Comment: Scratch marks are a normal part of sheet metal work, the copper will start turning colors unless there is a clear coat then the scratches will turn before the suns uv rays degrade the clear coat. Every bend where the copper goes into the space between the bricks and at the bottom bend s are points where the clear coat cracks and will start developing its patina. I could not see the top fold in the left hand side that and step flashing are why I said sub par. As Jack mentioned where the dis similar metals meet the galvanic corrosion will eat the metal the least noble metal is consumed.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, very helpful. My contractor used clear silicon instead of mortar to fill the gaps between the copper and bricks. When i insisted on mortar he says silicon is just fine. Thoughts ?